# Amazon Cloudfront being being translated to wrong url

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-cloudfront

I am hosting websites from one server, say example.com and blog.example.com. Server is using Apache 1, its httpd conf by default points to example.com
it also contains a virtual host that points to blog.example.com.

The website hosted at example.com is using Amazon cloud front, everything was good until I hosted the second website, Now cloud front is translating into blog.example.com. 
Nothing has been changed, just added a virtual host.

gugjhgjgjhgj@cloudfrontnet should look for example.com but its looking from blog.example.com which is being hosted on the same server.

Comment: what have you written in the Alternative CNAME field of cloudfront?

Comment: it is empty as of now